# What are the differences between the data compression filters in HDF5

Tags: compression, hdf5

[HDF5 API](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5P.html#Property-SetFilter) states that there are four main filters (i.e., gzip, szip, N-bit, and scale-offset) one can employ for data compression. I wonder what are their main differences from one another in terms of their multicore performances?

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf5-quest.html#pneed
compression is not supported in parallel HDF5. If You mean JAVA multithreading by "multicore", then I have tried it only with NetCDF4 interface (which is built upon HDF5), and there multithreading actually causes more problems than solves. Providing a code example might actually clarify Your question.

Comment: Mine was a general question regarding the multicore performances of the filters one can use for data compression in "sequential" HDF5. Thus, I didn't write any code for this. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, got it. In that case the (multicore)performance of compression libraries should be independent of HDF5 itself, shouldn't it? Multithreading does not seem to be well supported in HDF5, I/O is done in serial way even for different files, at least in JAVA code.